# Centering child divs within a parent div

Tags: html, css

I want the max width of the "circlecontainer" to be 300px.
but when the browser exceeds 1200px in width, I want my 4 child divs (with max width 300px) to stay centered in the browser.
They are currently positioned on the left side.

Here is my html and css.

any tips would be appreciated :)

```css
.getstartedcirclescontainer {
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3329ff, white);
}

.circlecontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 24.9%;
  padding-top: 175px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 300px;
}

.circle1 {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8680ff, #5a52ff);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .66);
}
```

```html
<div class="getstartedcirclescontainer">

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `text-align: center;` with `justify-content: center;` for `.getstartedcirclescontainer`.

HTML:

```
<div class="getstartedcirclescontainer">

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle1">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.getstartedcirclescontainer {
      height: 650px;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      background-image: linear-gradient(#3329ff, white);
 }

.circlecontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 24.9%;
  padding-top: 175px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 300px;
}

.circle1 {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8680ff, #5a52ff);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #fff;

  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.66);
}
```